# How to apply the Picard-Lindelöf theorem to a non-autonomous system of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a equation on the form

$$ \dot{x_1} = x_2 $$

$$\dot{x_2} = \frac{1}{1-t^2}x_1 +\frac{2t}{1-t^2}x_2$$

and I need to find the interval on where the solution exist.

I know that the solution will exists if its  Lipschitz continous and that it will exists on the interval: $ T_0 = \min (T,\frac{\delta}{M}) $.

But how does it work when I have a matrix equation? Should I use the expression above, for $T_0$, for each entry and compute a interval and find one where all are bounded?

Answer (score 2):

Picard-Lindelöf works just as well for systems. Write it as $\vec x'=\vec f(t,\vec x)$. You'll need $\vec f$ to be Lipschitz in the second argument, and the interval of guaranteed existence will involve the Lipschitz constant.

But this particular problem is easier because $\vec f$ is linear in the second argument. For linear equations, the solution exists and is unique as long as the coefficients behave. That is, as long as $|t|<1$.

Comment: The first claim is not strictly true. If you have a subset of a domain with a Lipschitz constant on it, then you can extend any solution in finitely many steps to the boundaries of that domain. Or use a proof construction that directly establishes the solution in the maximal time domain that is possible for the ODE domain. So the existence of the Lipschitz constant is important, not its value.